# Exchange context objects like row in tableview

Tags: ios, tableview, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Good day. 
How can I change context objects in my managed object context when I use function `moveRowAtIndexPath:`? That is how it look with changing array values:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath{
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [slef ManagedObjectContext];

     [tasks exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndexPath:toIndexPath.row]; //tasks is my array
     [tableview reloadData];
}
```

So how can I exchange objects in that `context` and save it in Core Data?

Comment: What does `tasks` contain? Do the managed objects in `tasks` contain an `index` field?

Comment: Tasks is array whith fetched objects, which I get from MOC.

Comment: Ok, but how do you set their initial order in the array? I presume that when you open the app, you expect the order `tasks` to be the one from the previous session (after moving some rows). You need to persist this order, and you can't do it without having a field in your `tasks` objects that tells them of their order. Please provide the header for your managed object (used in `tasks`), and the fetch request for populating `tasks`.

Comment: You mean this? : `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Tasks"];
    self.tasks = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider your `Tasks` object. You'll need to add a field that will be used at sorting.
Inside `Tasks.h`

```
@interface Tasks : NSManagedObject
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * index;  // also update your codedata model to add a numeric 'index' field to it (Integer 64 for instance)
@end
```

Also synthesize it in the implementation (`@dynamic index;`);

Wherever you want to fetch the tasks:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

// set the sort descriptors to handle the sorting
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];

self.tasks = [[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[request release];
```

finally, handle reordering:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath{
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [slef ManagedObjectContext];

     Tasks *tfrom = [tasks objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
     Tasks *tto = [tasks objectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
     tfrom.index = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:toIndexPath.row];
     tto.index = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:fromIndexPath.row];
     // preferably save the context, to make sure the new order will persist
     [managedObjectContext save:nil];  // where managedObjectContext is your context

     [tasks exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndexPath:toIndexPath.row]; //tasks is my array
     [tableview reloadData];
}
```

If you already have existing `Tasks` objects, you'll need to set them the `index` field, such that no 2 tasks have the same index.